# Springboot embedded mongo test

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, embedded-database

I am trying to test a simple SpringBoot application with Embedded Mongo but my repository is getting set to `null`. Can anyone spot what I am missing?

//Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepo;

    public MyController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/test")
    public Iterable<Test> findAll() {
        return myRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

//Empty repository interface

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository< Test, String> {
}
```

//Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

//Integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    MyController controller;

    @Autowired
    MyRepository myRepo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        controller = new MyController();
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testing() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = get("/test").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn().getResponse();

        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
```

//Dependencies in gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:1.50.5"
    testCompile group: 'cz.jirutka.spring', name: 'embedmongo-spring', version: '1.3.1'
}
```

`myRepo.findAll()` is `null` - how can this get set? Will it work out of the box with embedded mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `MongoRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` when working with MongoDB.
- Your integration test is for verifying end-to-end behavior of the system, so there is no need to include the controller or repository in your test class. Try to use the following:

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest
  public class MyIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void testing() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test"))
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()) 
      }
  }
  ```